# How to install ffmpeg on linux(centos 6.8) dedicated server

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos

I want to install ffmpeg on my linux(centos 6.8) dedicated server using
**yum install ffmpeg** command,But I am getting below error:-

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
http://dl.atrpms.net/el6-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"
Trying other mirror.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: atrpms. Please verify its path and try again

When I tried to fix above and used to add DAG Repository I could not succeed

Comment: what does `yum search ffmpeg` give you? maybe you are missing some repo's

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
It gives this error:http://dl.atrpms.net/el6-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: atrpms. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: It gives above error

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 for example? because it seems you dont have internet connectivity.

Comment: You need the RPMFusion repos (and with centos also EPEL repos) both can be installed as written at @ https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration under the Centos /RHEL section.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the atrpms repository is no longer functional https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229661/is-atrpms-dead .
You should remove it from your repos list. You can get ffmpeg from the nux-dextop repository. Instructions here: http://ask.xmodulo.com/enable-nux-dextop-repository-centos-rhel.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to [download a static build of `ffmpeg`](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). This is an already compiled binary from recent FFmpeg code. All you need to do is download, extract, and execute; no need to install anything.